# GridView not displaying all tables in dataset

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding, dataset

I'm trying to bind data to an ASP GridView, but it only displays the data from the first table in my dataset. Can someone please tell me why all of the tables are not displaying as I expect? I have confirmed there are multiple tables with data in each in the dataset.

I've tried using a auto formatted gridview, and a new gridview with no formatting and I get the same results. All I want to do is display every table in the dataset in the gridview. All tables have the same table structure. I've also tried looping through each table in the dataset and tried to bind each table to the gridview, but that does not work either.

```
string xmlData = ds.GetXml();
string filePath = "c:\\dataset.xml"; //confirmed tables are in dataSet
ds.WriteXml(filePath);

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: GridViews only display one DataTable. You'll need to use multiple GridViews if you want multiple tables, and implement some sort of UI (like tabs or a menu) to switch between them. Alternatively, join your tables together into one DataTable.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I think joining them together will work best for what I'm doing since there will be a lot of tables.